# How to show a correct scale for mercator-based maps in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, google, satellite

To be more specific:

I have created a map in Pseudo-Mercator `EPSG: 3857` using Google Satellite.
So my layers, and my project, are all set to Pseudo-Mercator.

How can I create a map in print composer which shows me a right scale?

I mean, when I create a map of my area, I know that the scale is wrong when compared to official maps of that area (my map shows a smaller area of the world).

I cannot indicate the scale (e.g. 1/10000) because it is wrong.

What can I do? How can i create maps in typical scales like 1:10000 or 1:100000 which are correct?

I am using QGIS 2.18.2.

Comment: Reprojecting to an appropriate local projection will solve this issue. The choice depends on your area of interest's location.

Comment: With EPSG:3857 the scale is different for North-South and East-West anywhere else but on top of the equator. If you want correct scales you'll do as @underdark suggests.

Comment: So to be clear, I created a map with Google Satellite as my base. The map is a quite remote area in Burkina Faso. So I used the Google Satellite image to draw my lines (on paths for example), polygons for houses, etc. I want to print maps with a correct scale. Reprojection sounds good. How do I do this? Is WGS 84 / UTM Zone 30N considered a local projection? Do I set my project CRS to WGS 84 / UTM Zone 30N or do i have to save my layers with a new CRS. Will this be correct? How can I verify my results?

Comment: UTM Zone 30N looks suitable http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32630/. Read this http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html and set OTF to EPSG:32630 and you should be about ready for printing at scale.

Comment: I am still not sure how to do it. Do i simply have to set my Project CRS to UTM Zone 30N or do I have to save my layers in UTM?